# MySQL: Select top 5 rows based on ID and find Subtotal

Tags: mysql

### Need to select top 5 rows for each id based on desc values of a particular column , value and find the subtotal of that column . for e.g (*Tried creating the situation , actual table structure is large* )

```
ID  VALUE   
1   2       
1   3       
1   4       
1   5       
1   6       
1   7       
1   8       
2   9       
2   10      
2   11      
2   12      
2   13      
2   14
```

Output Expected

```
ID     VALUE
1        8
1        7
1        6
1        5
1        4
TOTAL   30
2       14
2       13
2       12
2       11
2       10
TOTAL   60
```

I could select top 5 rows using a code like this ;

```
@cust_rank := IF(@current_cust = id, @cust_rank + 1, 1) AS cust_rank,
                 @current_cust := id
```

and then selecting top 5

Also ,I could subtotal using code like this ;

```
SELECT id, value FROM source
UNION
SELECT NULL,SUM(value) FROM source
GROUP BY id ORDER BY id;
```

> I need to merge both requirements .

Comment: The output looks like a spreadsheet, not a database table: do you _really_ want a table whose first column has either an id or the word `TOTAL` ?

Comment: I used the word "Total" just to make it better to understand .

Comment: OK, but do you _really_ want the subtotals in the same column as the values? If you provide more context, explaining what you want to do with those data, how your application will use them, maybe we can find a better solution than a spreadsheet-like table with data and totals mixed in the same column...

Comment: yes , the total should appear right after those 5 rows selected . I have to apply this logic to many columns . I need this format of data and subtotal together , as this needs to be reported in a spreadsheet .

Comment: It seems that ultimately you just want the sum of the top 5 rows per user . But if so, this isn't clear from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST(id as CHAR(50)) Id, value
FROM (SELECT id , value ,
             IF(@lastid=(@lastid:=id), @auto:=@auto+1, @auto:=1) indx 
      FROM source, (SELECT @lastid:=0, @auto:=1) A 
      ORDER BY id,value desc)as A  
WHERE indx <= 5
```

Output

```
Id  value
1   8
1   7
1   6
1   5
1   4
2   14
2   13
2   12
2   11
2   10
```

2nd Query

```
SELECT 'Total', SUM(value)
FROM (SELECT id , value ,
             IF(@lastid=(@lastid:=id), @auto:=@auto+1, @auto:=1) indx 
      FROM source, (SELECT @lastid:=0, @auto:=1) A 
      ORDER BY value desc)as A  
WHERE indx <= 5 
GROUP BY id ;
```

Output

```
Total   SUM(value)
Total   30
Total   60
```

Merged Query:

```
Select 
CASE
    WHEN indx =6 THEN "Total"
    ELSE id
END as ID,value
from
(
  select id,value,
IF(@lastid=(@lastid:=id), @auto:=@auto+1, @auto:=1) indx 
FROM
(
SELECT CAST(id as CHAR(50)) Id, value
FROM (SELECT id , value ,
             IF(@lastid=(@lastid:=id), @auto:=@auto+1, @auto:=1) indx 
      FROM source, (SELECT @lastid:=0, @auto:=1) A 
      ORDER BY id,value desc)as A  
WHERE indx <= 5
UNION
SELECT CAST(id as CHAR(50))as id, SUM(value)as value
FROM (SELECT id , value ,
             IF(@lastid1=(@lastid1:=id), @auto1:=@auto1+1, @auto1:=1) indx 
      FROM source, (SELECT @lastid1:=0, @auto1:=1) A 
      ORDER BY value desc)as A  
WHERE indx <= 5 
GROUP BY id)as output ,(SELECT @lastid:=0, @auto:=1) A ORDER BY id) as output1
```

Output

```
ID    value
1       8
1       7
1       6
1       5
1       4
Total   30
2       10
2       11
2       12
2       13
2       14
Total   60
```

Comment: thank you . I am able to do this seperately . As said above i have to merge both these requirements into one .

Comment: Please accept the answer if you got your answer!! @Me-si

Comment: The format is perfect , but it returns the sum of all values for that id and not the top 5 selected values .

Comment: used another alias table after "SUM(value)as value
FROM" till WHERE indx <= 5  , and it worked . thank you

Comment: UPvote the question if it was clear and showed research effort