# Postgresql select top 5 marks rows for every unique student id

Tags: database, postgresql

This is one of my views called xyz:

```
ID | NAME |......Other Data... | Marks
1    A                100
1    A                100 
1    A                99
1    A                95
1    A                94
1    A                94
1    A                94
1    A                91
1    A                87
1    A                86
2    B                100
2    B                94
2    B                93
2    B                90
2    B                89
2    B                89
2    B                87
2    B                86
3    C                100
3    C                98
3    C                98
3    C                97
3    C                92
3    C                91
3    C                90
```

The query I used to get this is something like this:

```
create or replace view xyz as
select * 
from abc 
where id in 
          (select id 
           from data) 
order by id, mark desc, id;
```

And based on unique ids I want the top 5 rows:

```
ID | NAME |......Other Data... | Marks
1    A                100
1    A                100
1    A                99
1    A                95
1    A                94
2    B                100
2    B                94
2    B                93
2    B                90
2    B                89
3    C                100
3    C                98
3    C                98
3    C                97
3    C                92
```

I tried referring to this:

[MySQL: Select top 5 rows based on ID and find Subtotal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49249177/mysql-select-top-5-rows-based-on-id-and-find-subtotal)

But I wasn't able to do it. Could you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [windowed `rank()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS), partitioned by each student name, and ordered by marks descending, to find the top 5 marks for each Student:

```
WITH cteRankedMarks AS
(
   SELECT "ID", "NAME", "Marks", 
    rank() OVER (PARTITION BY "NAME"
            ORDER BY "Marks" DESC)  AS rank
    FROM MyTable
)
 SELECT "ID", "NAME", "Marks" 
  FROM cteRankedMarks
  WHERE rank <= 5  
  ORDER BY "NAME", "Marks" DESC;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5ad4a2/3)

*Notes*

- If two or more marks have the same value vying for 5th place, then , then `rank` will return all such marks. If you don't want ties, then use `row_number()` instead of `rank()`. [More about these here](https://www.eversql.com/rank-vs-dense_rank-vs-row_number-in-postgresql/)
- Obviously, if a student doesn't have 5 marks, then fewer rows will be returned.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it so well. Really helped!

Comment: You're welcome - that link to the MySql hack just reinforces how infinitely superior PG is to MySql :)